# Angular directive with routeParams

Tags: angularjs

Can the following pattern be replaced:

```
.directive('currentStep', ['$log', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $log.log("tmsstep is: " + scope.tmsstep);
            return attrs.currentStep === scope.tmsstep;
        }
    };
}]);
```

To access the routeParams directly something like (which doesn't seem to work):

```
.directive('currentStep', ['$log', '$routeParams' , function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $log.log("tmsstep is: " + $routeParams.tmsstep);
            return attrs.currentStep === $routeParams.tmsstep;
        }
    };
}]);
```

The purpose is to avoid having tmsstep in both $scope and $routeParams

Comment: You are missing the `$routeParams` parameter to your directive method.

Comment: function($log) or function(scope, element, attrs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not realize that your supposed to modify the DOM-directly from the directive. Just returning True/false was not what i wanted to do. element.css('display', none) was needed.

`function($log, $routeParams)` was the correct syntax for the directive method